# Error writing to table using IBPP

Tags: c++, firebird

I have some problem writing to a firebird database using IBPP. I can make queries from tables without problems using the SELECT statement, but whenever I try to write values using IBPP::Set or IBPP::Execute, I get an error.

This is how I connect to my database:

```
db = IBPP::DatabaseFactory(settings.ServerName, settings.DbName, settings.UserName, settings.Password,
    "WIN1252", "PAGE_SIZE 8192 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET WIN1252");
db->Connect();
IBPP::Transaction tr = IBPP::TransactionFactory(db);
IBPP::Statement st = IBPP::StatementFactory(db, tr);
```

Then I wanted to set a specific value:

```
st->Execute("UPDATE T_GEOMODELL SET Distance= 42.0 WHERE (OBJEKT_ID = 1756056);");
```

I also tried

```
st->Prepare("SELECT * FROM T_GEOMODELL WHERE OBJEKT_ID = 1756056");
st->Set(6, "41");
st->Execute();
```

Here I get the error that "this->mOutRow" is "nullptr".

With the Firebird ISQL tool however, the same command

```
UPDATE T_GEOMODELL SET Distance= 42.0 WHERE (OBJEKT_ID = 1756056);
```

works without problems.

I am using Visual C++ 2015 under x64.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your second attempt (which includes (`st->Set(6, "41")`) of course is not going to work, you are trying to set the sixth parameter of a statement that has no parameters. Please be more explicit in what code produces exactly what error (and please, post the full exception or error information).

Comment: Also, exactly what are you trying to achieve? Your question suggests you are trying to update value, but why does your second example then try to use a select statement?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  Thanks for your help. I want to update an existing value. I hoped the second example with the SELECT statement would give me the same result.

Comment: It seems I just found the error  - I had to start and commit the transaction using tr->Start(); and tr->Commit();. Many thanks tho for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the error - I had to start and commit the transaction using tr->Start(); and tr->Commit();

```
tr->Start();
st->Execute("UPDATE T_GEOMODELL SET Distance= 42.0 WHERE (OBJEKT_ID = 1756056);");
tr->Commit();
```